# VB6 Com dll(XYZ.dll) referenced in VS 2005 renamed as interop.XYZ.dll

Tags: vb.net, dll, com, com-interop

Simple question perhaps.The project has a VB-COM Dll that was renamed as interop.dllname.dll in the references. now, if I try to remove and include a new reference( to the same dll), it is not renamed but added as it is.

Any idea why the renaming didn't occur?

Comment: FYI, it doesn't "rename" it, it creates a whole new dll.  The Interop dll is not a copy of the original COM dll.  It is an actual .NET library assembly which provides interoperability between .NET and the COM library.  It has all the same classes with the same public interfaces as the COM library, but when you call it, it just in-turn, makes the equivalent call out to the COM library for you, performing any data conversions and object marshaling as necessary.

Comment: thanks and agreed. My point is when I try to add the reference,it no longer creates a reference to interop.xyz.dll . It just creates a reference to xyz.dll. Any thoughts on why the referred dll is no longer named interop.xyz.dll ?

Comment: Are you adding it as a COM reference, as a .NET reference, or are you browsing to the dll to add it?

Comment: COM. Browsing the dll and adding the ref also has the same result.

Comment: No, you should be selecting it from the COM tab in the dialog window.  I don't know why that would be failing to create the interop.  I've never heard of it doing that.  Hopefully someone else will have an answer for you.  By the way, are you absolutely sure that the original COM dll is still actually a COM dll and hasn't been overwritten by a .NET assembly, such as the Interop?  Have you tried unregistering and reregistering it?

Comment: Yes. I have re-built the VB6 dll just to make sure i am adding the correct reference.

Comment: Just realized that the reference in the Solution explorer window shows it as XYZ and the properties show it as interop.xyz. So this is just a display issue. I'd still would love to know what made it to drop the prefix when adding the ref. - thanks